# Difference for Widget.ProgressBar.Small and Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse

Tags: android

I try out two different progress bar styles for action bar button, through

```
refreshMenuItem.setActionView(R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
```

### actionbar_indeterminate_progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle" >
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I had tried **Widget.ProgressBar.Small** and **Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse**. However, I do not see any visual difference.

### Widget.ProgressBar.Small

[image]

### Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse

[image]

I expect there is an *inverse* in color but there isn't. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a slight difference, but it's difficult to notice at first.

The `Widget.ProgressBar.Small` style version is intended to be placed over dark backgrounds while the `Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse` style version is intended to be placed over light backgrounds.

Normally you would probably not notice this. The best way to check it is to put the combinations of the two progress bars on black and white backgrounds and display it a on good display, then you can notice differences on the edges.

Comment: Should it be reverse? : The "inverse" styles provide an inverse color scheme for the spinner, which may be necessary if your application uses a light colored theme (a white background).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I messed it up and wrote it the other way around. Now, it should be correct.